# Команды Docker не работают без sudo

Tags: linux, docker, sudo

Нужно, чтобы команды docker запускались без sudo. Был добавлен юзер в группу докера

```
    sudo groupadd docker
    sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Но все равно при попытке выполнить команды получаю ошибку

```
user@user-ET2013I:~$ docker ps -a
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/user/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Ошибка исчезает только если выполнять команду через sudo. Как можно пофиксить?

UPD Да, система после добавления пользователя перезапускалась

- В sudo ps -ef | grep dockerd

```
root         808       1  7 10:32 ?        00:01:14 dockerd --group docker --exec-root=/run/snap.docker --data-root=/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker --pidfile=/run/snap.docker/docker.pid --config-file=/var/snap/docker/2343/config/daemon.json
root        1346       1  0 10:32 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
user       68501   68438  0 10:50 pts/6    00:00:00 grep --color=auto dockerd
```

- В /lib/systemd/system/docker.socket

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Socket for the API

[Socket]
# If /var/run is not implemented as a symlink to /run, you may need to
# specify ListenStream=/var/run/docker.sock instead.
ListenStream=/run/docker.sock
SocketMode=0660
SocketUser=root
SocketGroup=docker

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

- В /lib/systemd/system/docker.service

```
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=https://docs.docker.com
After=network-online.target docker.socket firewalld.service containerd.service time-set.target
Wants=network-online.target containerd.service
Requires=docker.socket

[Service]
Type=notify
# the default is not to use systemd for cgroups because the delegate issues still
# exists and systemd currently does not support the cgroup feature set required
# for containers run by docker
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
TimeoutStartSec=0
RestartSec=2
Restart=always
```

- В sudo systemctl status docker

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset>
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-02-09 10:56:41 EET; 2min 7s ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
   Main PID: 1465 (dockerd)
      Tasks: 8
     Memory: 83.3M
        CPU: 501ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
             └─1465 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/cont>

фев 09 10:56:39 user-ET2013I dockerd[1465]: time="2023-02-09T10:56:39.781463532>
фев 09 10:56:40 user-ET2013I dockerd[1465]: time="2023-02-09T10:56:40.189176429>
фев 09 10:56:40 user-ET2013I dockerd[1465]: time="2023-02-09T10:56:40.222288085>
фев 09 10:56:41 user-ET2013I dockerd[1465]: time="2023-02-09T10:56:41.044548848>
фев 09 10:56:41 user-ET2013I dockerd[1465]: time="2023-02-09T10:56:41.285711286>
фев 09 10:56:41 user-ET2013I dockerd[1465]: time="2023-02-09T10:56:41.431369971>
фев 09 10:56:41 user-ET2013I dockerd[1465]: time="2023-02-09T10:56:41.432549997>
фев 09 10:56:41 user-ET2013I dockerd[1465]: time="2023-02-09T10:56:41.511188515>
фев 09 10:56:41 user-ET2013I systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container E>
фев 09 10:56:41 user-ET2013I dockerd[1465]: time="2023-02-09T10:56:41.546528554>
lines 1-22/22 (END)...skipping...
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-02-09 10:56:41 EET; 2min 7s ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
   Main PID: 1465 (dockerd)
      Tasks: 8
     Memory: 83.3M
        CPU: 501ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
             └─1465 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

фев 09 10:56:39 user-ET2013I dockerd[1465]: time="2023-02-09T10:56:39.781463532+02:00" level=info msg="[core] [Channel #4] Channel Connectivity change to READY" module=grpc
фев 09 10:56:40 user-ET2013I dockerd[1465]: time="2023-02-09T10:56:40.189176429+02:00" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2"
фев 09 10:56:40 user-ET2013I dockerd[1465]: time="2023-02-09T10:56:40.222288085+02:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
фев 09 10:56:41 user-ET2013I dockerd[1465]: time="2023-02-09T10:56:41.044548848+02:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16>
фев 09 10:56:41 user-ET2013I dockerd[1465]: time="2023-02-09T10:56:41.285711286+02:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
фев 09 10:56:41 user-ET2013I dockerd[1465]: time="2023-02-09T10:56:41.431369971+02:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=d7573ab graphdriver=overlay2 version=23.0.0
фев 09 10:56:41 user-ET2013I dockerd[1465]: time="2023-02-09T10:56:41.432549997+02:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
фев 09 10:56:41 user-ET2013I dockerd[1465]: time="2023-02-09T10:56:41.511188515+02:00" level=info msg="[core] [Server #7] Server created" module=grpc
фев 09 10:56:41 user-ET2013I systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
фев 09 10:56:41 user-ET2013I dockerd[1465]: time="2023-02-09T10:56:41.546528554+02:00" level=info msg="API listen on /run/docker.sock"
~
```

Comment: Перезапускать систему пробовали?

Comment: Какой-то у вас очень странный сокет `unix:///home/user/.docker/desktop/docker.sock`. С какими параметрами запущен `dockerd` (`sudo ps -ef | grep dockerd`)? Что написано в `/lib/systemd/system/docker.socket` и `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`?

Comment: Система была перезапущена много раз, но не помогает
На докер демон ругается только тогда, когда пытаюсь выполнить команды без sudo.

Comment: В sudo ps -ef | grep dockerd
root         808       1  8 10:32 ?        00:00:38 dockerd --group docker --exec-root=/run/snap.docker --data-root=/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker --pidfile=/run/snap.docker/docker.pid --config-file=/var/snap/docker/2343/config/daemon.json
root        1346       1  0 10:32 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
user       12282    9844  0 10:40 pts/4    00:00:00 grep --color=auto dockerd

Comment: В /lib/systemd/system/docker.socket
`[Socket]
# If /var/run is not implemented as a symlink to /run, you may need to
# specify ListenStream=/var/run/docker.sock instead.
ListenStream=/run/docker.sock
SocketMode=0660
SocketUser=root
SocketGroup=docker

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target`

Comment: Прикрепляю все к первому сообщению, а то в комменты не влазит

Comment: У вас два докер-демона запущены, один из `snap`, второй из `systemd`. Я бы на вашем месте удалил snap.docker и перезагрузился

Comment: Докер из snap удален. Не помогло...

Comment: Кажется, я знаю, в чем проблема. Как найти где указан этот путь? Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/user/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Answer (score 1):

сдается мне что у вас демон Docker не запущен.

При нехватке прав должно выдаваться что-то вроде: "Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at ...", а у вас там "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/user/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?"

что с самим докером?

$ sudo systemctl status docker

или

$ sudo service docker status

Comment: Как вы тогда объясните что с sudo по заявлению автора оно работает?

Comment: после `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER` этого вам нужно выйти и войти в систему снова, чтобы изменения вступили в силу. После этого вы можете запускать Docker без sudo

Answer (score 0):

В документации написано, что если первый раз запускалось под sudo, то возникают проблемы с правами к настройкам. В вашем вопросе тоже недоступен ресурс из каталога /home/user/.docker

Посмотрите права доступа к каталогу `~/.docker`

И попробуйте сменить владельца:

```
 sudo chown "$USER":"$USER" /home/"$USER"/.docker -R
 sudo chmod g+rwx "$HOME/.docker" -R
```

Comment: Не помогло...
У меня был докер десктоп и пришлось его полностью снести и заменить на docker.io. Но путь к демону где-то остался как докер.десктоп. Где этот путь можно увидеть?

Answer (score 0):

В общем, причина, скорее всего, в том, что раньше у меня стоял докер десктоп, а потом понадобилась более старая версия. Но докер демон все еще ищет докер десктоп. Пока не могу найти, где именно прописывается этот путь, но причина, видимо, именно в этом...

Docker daemon at unix:///home/user/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Answer (score 0):

Также было, оказывается после установки и удаления Docker Desktop докер запомнил путь к docker.sock, которого уже не было.
Посмотри, какой путь использует докер `docker context ls`, а затем выполни `docker context use default`. Так он будет использовать путь /var/run/docker.sock.